# Python format dict data

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a dictionary called dag_data and I am trying to format the different items in the list into a string using the following code:

```
text += f"{dag_data['is_late_by']:<9} {dag_data['last_successful_run']:<27}\n"
```

I am basically trying to left justify 'is_late_by' and 'last_successful_run'. But the above syntax does not work. I don't get an error when I try to execute this code but I don't get any output either. Any pointers as to what I am missing will really help.

Comment: I don't think you mean _list_.  _list_ indices must be integers or slices, not strings.  Did you mean _dict_?

Comment: Yes I meant dict @Wyck

Comment: You don't get **any** output?  I mean, if `dag_data` is `{ "is_late_by":1, "last_successful_run":2 }` then the result will look like `'1         2                          \n'`

Comment: It was an issue with the data type. I modified all values to string and it worked. Thanks!